# How to delete duplicate photo album?

Tags: iphone

I wanted to create a separate photo album with my wallpapers on my iPhone 4s. So I synced the photos from my computer, but now on my phone I have my "Wallpapers" album and a duplicate album "Photo Library", I tried deleting one or the other but that option is unavailable.

Does anyone know how I can resolve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try emptying the album before deleting?

Answer (score 1):

From the photos app on the iphone press edit on the top-right corner and press on the *minus* sign before the album you want to remove. The camera roll/Photo Library cannot be deleted because it is pre-made by the operating system.